# New PC Build w/ Asus P8P67 Pro and 16 GB DDR3 1333 RAM, only 8GB shows on System

Tags: windows-7, memory

I just built my first PC and only 8 of 16 GB Ram shows up on the system.  I took out all of the RAM and put it in a different order, turned it on and 16GB Ram showed up.  But when I restarted the computer, it was back to 8 GB.  Is this a memory, motherboard, or OS problem? Here are the components in the computer:

- **RAM:** 4GBx2 Mushkin 996770 DDR3 1333 (2 orders of this)
- **GPU:** ASUS ENGTX460 DIRECTCU/2DI/1GD5
- **PSU:** Corsair CMPSU-750HX 750W RT
- **CPU:** Intel Core-i5 2500K 3.3GHz
- **HDD:** 1TB Samsung HD103SJ
- **OS:** Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 1):

- Try running software like [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) to make sure that all of the RAM works
- Check in the BIOS if it displays the full amount of RAM. If it does show the full amount in the BIOS, but not in Windows, it may be an OS problem. If it does not show the full amount in the BIOS, it is definitely a hardware problem
- I checked; your processor and motherboard both support up to 32GB of RAM, so it's not a compatibility problem

Comment: I shut down to check the RAM in the BIOS and it showed 16384 MB. Before it was abou 8000 GB. And now the 16 GB shows up in Windows Control Panel.  Unfortunately, I think it will go back to 8 GB again.  So can Memory be faulty?  Or is it the Motherboard?  btw, thanks for the feedback

Comment: I think you probably mean 8000MB. If it said 8000GB, something is definitely wrong ;). The next time the wrong amount appears in Windows, reboot and check the BIOS. If the problem keeps occurring, I would definitely try doing the memory test I mentioned. If that comes up clean, you can rule out memory problems, meaning it's probably a motherboard issue. Are there any other motherboards (yours or a friend's) you could test your RAM in?

Comment: PS, once you get 15 reputation points, you can thank users for their answers on your posts or other people's posts by clicking the upvote arrow next to their post. You can also vote up questions, which gives reputation as well. Welcome to Super User!

Comment: @Ethan has the problem reoccurred or is it working with the full amount of RAM now?

Comment: thanks for the follow up.  I finally booted from memtest, which I had trouble mounting to disc at first. It shows 16 GB of memory cached.  I increased DRAm voltage out of another recommendation on Toms Hardware to 1.6.  but problem persists.  May try to clean contacts but it looks like motherboard issue. Maybe update bios?

Comment: If you're still having problems, I would try to find another motherboard to test in - one belonging to a friend or something. That would tell you if it's an issue with the RAM or the motherboard. Then, if the RAM is indeed defective, I would try to send the RAM back as I presume it's probably still under warranty.

Comment: So I finally did some tests.  I tested each memory stick one at a time and used memtest.  They all passed.  Then I tested the slots on the motherboard.  If there were three memory sticks(12 GB), sometimes the BIOS would only read 8GB.  After some switching around, I determined that maybe I didn't install it correctly.  I then installed all of the sticks carefully to make sure they were locked in and the BIOS read 16 GB.  Unfortunately the next time I booted it up it only read 8GB.  I'm getting my P8P67 replacement next week because of the Sandy Bridge mess so I will see if that changes it,